# Jboss AS 7, error in web service basic http autentication

Tags: jax-ws, jboss7.x, ws-security, jaas

I've developed a Ejb-based web service, in a jboss eap 6.1 application server.
Without autentication this service works as expected.
Now, I've added a basic autentication mechanism to this web service, following the steps I've performed:

I've annotated my ejb (wich implements the ws) in the following way:

```
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.SecurityDomain;
import org.jboss.ws.api.annotation.WebContext;

@Stateless
@WebService(name = "HelloWorldWS", targetNamespace="http://my-company/ws/")
@WebContext(authMethod = "BASIC", contextRoot = "helloWS", urlPattern ="/*")
@SecurityDomain("helloworld-webservice-login")


public class HelloWorldWebService implements HelloWorldWebServiceRemote {

@RolesAllowed({"mioruolo"})
public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello World";
}
}
```

and, according to that, I've added the helloworld-webservice-login security domain in my standalone.xml file, as follows:

```
<security-domain name="helloworld-webservice-login">
                        <authentication>
                                <login-module code="Database"    flag="required">
                                        <module-option name="dsJndiName"      value="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"/>
                                        <module-option     name="principalsQuery" value="select password from s_principals where principal_id=?"/>
                                    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role, 'Roles' from s_roles where principal_id=?"/>                                       
                            </login-module>
                    </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

So, I would like that, only users with a role named "mioruolo" can access to the webservice.
I have added the tables s_roles and s_principals in my oracle 10g database, and I've executed the two queries that are in the xml file in a Toad window and both the two work as expected.

I use a jax-ws generated client to invoke this web service, and I pass credentials in the HTTP header in the following way, at the client-side:

```
 bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "federico");
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "passwd");
```

The response I get is always a 403-forbidden status code.
I checked jboss log file and I sow the following lines:

```
14:50:40,693 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.authenticator]         (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Security checking request POST /helloWS
14:50:40,694 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[HelloWorldWebService]' against POST / --> true
14:50:40,709 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[HelloWorldWebService]' against POST / --> true
14:50:40,709 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
14:50:40,709 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   User data constraint has no restrictions
14:50:40,710 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  Calling authenticate()
14:50:41,287 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Authenticated 'federico' with type 'BASIC'
14:50:41,288 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  Calling accessControl()
14:50:41,288 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   Checking roles GenericPrincipal[federico(mioruolo,)]
14:50:41,321 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  Failed accessControl() test
```

So, the autentication goes OK, but the authorization (I think the check if "federico" user has "mioruolo" role), fails, and I can not figure out the reason, as the query, executed in a Toad client executes without problems.

Any idea about this error?
Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you very much

regards

Comment: `select role, 'Roles' from s_roles where principal_id=?`. That query shouldn't work because of the comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to declare the roles in your HelloWorldWebService:

```
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.SecurityDomain;
import org.jboss.ws.api.annotation.WebContext;

@Stateless
@WebService(name = "HelloWorldWS", targetNamespace="http://my-company/ws/")
@WebContext(authMethod = "BASIC", contextRoot = "helloWS", urlPattern ="/*")
@SecurityDomain("helloworld-webservice-login")

@javax.annotation.security.DeclareRoles.DeclareRoles({"mioruolo"})

public class HelloWorldWebService implements HelloWorldWebServiceRemote {

@RolesAllowed({"mioruolo"})
public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello World";
}
}
```